# When I use model.save(filepath) for keras sequential it said this message on the picture

Tags: tensorflow, keras

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1Fgl.jpg)
It also happens when I directly import TFOptimizer.
How can I successfully save the model?

Comment: Hello @GIYEON LEE, consider adding messages as text in your question. This improves the visibility and searchability of your question.

Comment: Please show the line, where you compile your model.

Comment: Kindly add some code @GIYEON